# うん and ます form in the same sentence

Tags: politeness, japanese-to-english, style

https://twitter.com/MRko_aki___/status/1395581370328489985
A Japanese artist recently tweeted

> うん、頑張ります

What is the stylistic reason for combining the casual うん with the polite 頑張ります rather than はい?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To him, perhaps "うん、頑張る" might have sounded too personal, but "はい、頑張ります" might have sounded too official. This tweet sounds as if he first said うん to himself to make up his mind, and then said 頑張ります to externally declare his stance. In other words, he wanted to signal that this was basically a personal tweet, but at the same time, he was aware that he had to say something externally and many people would read this.